# Listbox owerflows when printing from IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, printing, listbox

When I print a page with a listbox from IE the content owerflows. This only happens in IE and it's only the actual print, the print preview looks good.

Here's a code sample:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="/IePrintTest.aspx" id="form1">
            <select size="4" name="Listbox" id="Listbox">
                <option value="item1">item1</option>
                <option value="item2">item2</option>
                <option value="item3">item3</option>
                <option value="item4">item4</option>
                <option value="item5">item5</option>
                <option value="item6">item6</option>
                <option value="item7">item7</option>
                <option value="item8">item8</option>
                <option value="item9">item9</option>
                <option value="item10">item10</option>
                <option value="item11">item11</option>
                <option value="item12">item12</option>
                <option value="item13">item13</option>
                <option value="item14">item14</option>
                <option value="item15">item15</option>
                <option value="item16">item16</option>
                <option value="item17">item17</option>
            </select>    
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This renders just fine, but if i try to print this from IE it will look like this:

[Image of print](http://i42.tinypic.com/2q1i8mq.jpg)

Does anyone know how to fix this.
Thanks!

Comment: I've never seen anything like it. Do you have any styles defined for the select element?

Comment: No, there no style defined for the select element.

Comment: which version of IE are you using? I copied the markup above and tested it in IE9 - it renders fine. Are you using any compatibility mode?

Comment: I'm using IE9, and yes it renders (IE 9 mode) just fine, the problem is when i try to print the web page, either send it to a printer (I tried multiple printer) or to pdf. If I remove the doctype IE kicks into Quirks mode and the print look fine, unfortunately it's not an option having IE running in Quriks mode.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like when printed from IE and `size` attribute is applied to `select`, the browser sets a fixed height and does not apply the overflow. I don't have the chance to test on IE as I am using Ubuntu, but can you please try to add a `style="overflow: hidden;"` to your `select` element? If it does not work and removing the `size` attribute is an option, try that as well.

Comment: Adding style="overflow: hidden" has no effect. If I remove the size attribute it will render as a dropdown, that not an option.

Answer (score 1):

How is the use case for this web page? If it's OK to make the user click a button first to open a print page you could serve a printable version of the content in quirks mode by making the serverscript conditionally add the DOCTYPE.

Comment: There is a print button on the page, and what you are suggesting is an option. But I would really like for the user to be able to use the print functionality in the browser.